# Laravel: efficient way to count related models with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I have two models `User` and `Posts`

- **User**: id,name
- **Post**: id,title,post,user_id

I want to check if some `user` has `posts` with given `title`.

```
$user = User::find($userId);
$posts = $user->posts;
$postsWithGivenTitle = $posts->where('title','=',$title);
$postCount = $postsWithGivenTitle->count();
```

I suppose this above should work but I need to go above this and do it efficiently. So I got this and it's working but still not sure is it the right way to do it.

```
$user = User::find($userId)->withCount(['posts' => function ($q) use ($title) {
    $q->where('title','=',$title);
}])->first();
```

and then to check the count:

```
if ($user->posts_count > 0) { 
    //do something
}
```

What's confusing me, and looks ugly, is using the methods `find()` and `first()` in the same query. So hopefully I'm missing something simple here and overthinking it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

You can acheive what you want like this:

```
$user = User::withCount(['posts' => function($q){....}])->find($id)
```